# Set date to fixed inteval php

Tags: php, date

I want to set in php a date with a variable delay as this example.

```
$date="2018-01-01"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date="2018-01-29"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date="2018-01-15"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date="2017-12-01"; // result : 2018-02-10
```

I know about the `strtotime("+2 month", $time)` to add 2 months to the date, but how i can fix the day?
Thank you so much.

Comment: please explain more .

Comment: Please check this url :-  http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/date-lastweek.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$date1="2018-01-01"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date2="2018-01-29"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date3="2018-01-15"; // result : 2018-03-10
$date4="2017-12-01"; // result : 2018-02-10

echo date('Y-m-10',strtotime("+2 month",strtotime($date1)))."<br>";
echo date('Y-m-10',strtotime("+2 month",strtotime($date2)))."<br>";
echo date('Y-m-10',strtotime("+2 month",strtotime($date3)))."<br>";
echo date('Y-m-10',strtotime("+2 month",strtotime($date4)))."<br>";
```

Here is [**Live Demo**](https://eval.in/931493)

Comment: You're Right my friend. Thank you so much!